# Android Fragment getArguments return null with bundle.putStringArrayList

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

getArguments return null,here's my code

```
public static ComplainFragment newInstance(ArrayList<String> list){
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putStringArrayList("info",list);
    ComplainFragment fragment = new ComplainFragment();
    fragment.setArguments(bundle);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Bundle bundle = getArguments();
    ArrayList<String> info = bundle.getStringArrayList("info");

}
```

The strange thing is that when passing data with bundle.putSerializable() or bundle.putString(),everything is OK.

Where is the error? Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: How you creating instance of `Fragment` ?

Comment: just call method `newInstance`

Comment: Then it should work..!!

Comment: Yes,it should! But it doesn't!